# Add to existing state within redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

What I am asking today is more of an expander than a reducer. So I have data at the moment:

```
[{"id":4729853,"MatItemKey":202029, "LongDesc":"2R Basket Label"},{"id":4729854,"MatItemKey":57561, "LongDesc":"Red Empty Basket Replacements"},
{"id":4729855,"MatItemKey":194135,"LongDesc":"BTS NOT REQUIRED"},{"id":4729856,"MatItemKey":210965,"LongDesc":"Heidi Heckelbeck Gets the Sniffles"},
{"id":4729857,"MatItemKey":132594,"LongDesc":"World's Longest Toenail, The"}]
```

But what I actually want to do for the list is expand it through my api, so call each id, get more data and fill each item with more details. Is there anything with redux to keep the current data structure, but add on any details from each call through axios to append the data? So far all of my calls have been getting new data, so the reducer basically just gets the data from axios and puts it in the store. But I was not sure what a pattern would be to add to existing state? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You certainly can do that, perhaps map over the array and update the object (with ```Object.assign()```) that matches the criteria, pseudo code: ```data.map(item => { if (isMatch(item, payload.id)) { return **payload** } return item }```

Comment: You can use either `Object.assign` to create a new copy of the object with additional properties or use the spread operator on the object and add the properties that way. For example, `{...state, newProperty: data}` or however many you want to add

Comment: Some immutability library like  immutability-helper are amazing for doing this:

https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper

Comment: good suggestions, everyone. Thanks. Will try all of these to see best method for me. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at immutable-js (it has lots of benefits). `Object.assign` or `{ ...currentState, ...additionalState }` works in ES6, `newState = currentState.merge(additionalState)` works in immutable.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the list from your state to the method that has the axios call. In the axios success callback, you can then map the list and append whatever data you want to add from the API. Using Array.prototype.map will create a new array. Then pass that new array as payload to your reducer.

Comment: how do I get the state into a function in an action creator? It isn't using the connect from redux.

Comment: Just pass them as normal function parameters. Just pass the particular props. Inside your action, pass the new immutable object as payload to your reducer.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to do it. It uses nothing on my action-creator. I am just passing the individual data for my axios call, for an individual item. Then in my reducer I have the following code that updates my state:

```
case UPDATE_BOOK:
    let newVals = state.map((item)=>{
        if(item.MatItemKey === action.meta.book.MatItemKey){
            return update(item, {$merge: action.payload.data})

        }else{
            return item
        }
    });
    console.log(newVals);
    return newVals
```

So with the immutability-helper I was able to update my data, using anything that was called to the state using axios. Thanks all for your suggestions, they all helped.